# Scala Array of different types of values

Tags: scala

Writing a function in Scala that accepts an Array/Tuples/Seq of different types of values and sorts it based on first two values in each:

```
def sortFunction[T](input: Array[T]) = input(0)+ " " + input(1)
```

The input values I have are as below:

```
val data = Array((1, "alpha",88.9), (2, "alpha",77), (2, "beta"), (3, "alpha"), (1, "gamma",99))
```

Then I call the sortFunction as:

```
data.sortWith(sortFunction)
```

It is giving below errors:

```
- polymorphic expression cannot be instantiated to expected type; found : [T]scala.collection.mutable.Seq[T] ⇒ Int required: ((Int, String)) ⇒ ? Error occurred in an application involving default arguments.
- type mismatch; found : scala.collection.mutable.Seq[T] ⇒ Int required: ((Int, String)) ⇒ ? Error occurred in an application involving default arguments.
```

What am I doing wrong, or how do I get around this? I would be grateful for any suggestions.

Comment: Your sort function doesn't sort anything.  It just takes the first two elements from the `Array` and tries to create a `String` out of them.

Comment: sortfunction does noting but  concatenating the given inputs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know type of element in Array[T], you can use pattern matching (when same type). But If You don't know, Program can't decide how to sort your data.

One of methods is just String compare like below.

```
object Hello{
  def sortFunction[T](input1: T, input2: T) =
    input1 match {
      case t : Product =>
        val t2 = input2.asInstanceOf[Product]
        t.productElement(0).toString < t2.productElement(0).toString
      case v => input1.toString > input2.toString
    }
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {


    val data = Array((1, "alpha",88.9), (2, "alpha",77), (2, "beta", 99), (3, "alpha"), (1, "gamma",99))

    println(data.sortWith(sortFunction).mkString)
  }
}
```

If you want to know Product tarit, see http://www.scala-lang.org/api/rc2/scala/Product.html

Answer (score 1):

If you have an `Array` of tuples that all have the same arity, such as tuples of `(Int, String)`, than your sort function could look something like

```
def sortFunction[T](fst: (Int, String), scd: (Int, String)) = fst._1 < scd._1 // sort by first element
```

However, since you have an `Array` of tuples of varying arity, Scala compiler can only put this under nearest common type `Product`. Then you can sort like this:

```
def sortFunction[T](fst: (Product), scd: (Product)) = fst.productElement(1).toString < scd.productElement(1).toString

val data = Array((1, "alpha", 99), (2, "alpha"), (2, "beta"), (3, "alpha"), (1, "gamma"))

data.sortWith(sortFunction) // List((1,alpha,99), (2,alpha), (3,alpha), (2,beta), (1,gamma))
```

Note that this is really bad design though. You should create an abstract data type that encapsulates your data in a more structured way. I can't say what it should look like since I don't know where and how you are getting this information, but here's an example (called `Foo`, but you should of course name it meaningfully):

```
case class Foo(index: Int, name: String, parameters: List[Int])
```

I just assumed that the first element in each piece of data is "index" and second one is "name". I also assumed that the rest of those elements inside will always be integers and that there may be zero, one or more of them, so hence a `List` (if it's only zero or one, better choice would be `Option`).

Then you could sort as:

```
def sortFunction[T](fst: Foo, scd: Foo) = fst.index < scd.index
```

or

```
def sortFunction[T](fst: Foo, scd: Foo) = fst.name < scd.name
```